# Add a for loop variable with another variable in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Form:

```
{% for user in users %}
  <tr>
      <td>{{ user.teammembers }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.level }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.skillset }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
      {% for dat in finaldatod %}
        <td>{{ user.dat }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Model:

```
class Jan17(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    slno = models.TextField(db_column='SLNo')
    teammembers = models.TextField(db_column='TeamMembers')
    level = models.TextField(db_column='Level')
    skillset = models.TextField(db_column='Skillset')
    employeeid = models.TextField(db_column='EmployeeID')
    pridid = models.TextField(db_column='PridID')
    jan01 = models.TextField(db_column='Jan01')
    jan02 = models.TextField(db_column='Jan02')
```

View:

```
def filter_users(request):
    form = UserlistForm(request.POST or None)
    users = None
    fromdate = None
    todate = None
    months = None
    finaldat = {}
    finaldatod = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            users = Jan17.objects.filter(Q(teammembers__contains=form.cleaned_data.get('teammembers')))
            fromdate = form.cleaned_data.get('fromdate')
            todate = form.cleaned_data.get('todate')
            months = form.cleaned_data.get('months')
            for dat in range(int(fromdate),int(todate)+1):
                if dat in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
                    findat = months + '0' + str(dat)
                else:
                    findat = months+str(dat)
                finaldat[findat] = findat
                finaldatod = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(finaldat.items()))

    return(render(request, 'useroutput.html', {'form': form, 'users': users, 'fromdate': fromdate, 'todate': todate, 'months': months, 'finaldatod': finaldatod}))
```

Template:

```
<form action="." enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">
{{ form.as_ul }}
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit">Search</button>

{% if users %}

<table border="5">
    <tr>
    <th>TeamMember</th>
    <th>Level</th>
    <th>SkillSet</th>
    <th>PridID</th>
    {% for dat in finaldatod %}
    <th>{{ dat }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.teammembers }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.level }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.skillset }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.pridid }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.jan01 }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.jan02 }}</td>
        {% for dat in finaldatod %}
        <td>{{ user.dat }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
```

Here `users` and `dat` are two dictionaries passed from my view.

- `users` has all the users available in the database
- `dat` has all the dates of the month

Now am able to fetch the `username`, `skillset`, `level` and `id` of all the users. But unable to fetch the shifts of the user for all the dates of the month.

Here `{{  user.dat  }}` is not working as its unable to substitute `user` value and `dat` value together.

Kindly advise how I can pass the values from first for loop to the second and get the data from the database.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What `finaldatod` is ?

Comment: finaldatod is a dictionary having dates like jan01,jan02,jan03,etc.
users is a dictionary having all users like Jon,Phil,etc
i want to fetch the database entry of Jon.jan01,Jon.jan02,Phil.jan01 etc.

Comment: So, if you do `{{ dat }}` instead of `{{ user.dat }}`, will not work?

Comment: if I use {{ dat }} its printing only jan01, jan02 etc. I want the data in the database like "First Shift" when i use Jon.jan01.

Comment: Is `dat` related to the `User` model? Essentially you're trying to do the kinds of things you should get the view or a utility function to do. A view should just display data in a given structure, not form the structure itself.

Comment: You need to show the view that is generating these dicts; I don't really understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: have updated my question with all the required files. Could you please check and help me out.